# HTML to PDF , Result columns are empty

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am using following codes to create pdf.

first **memberinfo.php** page contains table with name, address, city etc of member from mysql database. This file is in www.example.com/admin folder

second is **member_pdf.php** it it used to create PDF. It is in www.example.com/admin/do-pdf/dompdf/ folder

Code in **memberinfo.php** :

```
<?
 include("../include/function.php"); // to connect database
// Create an object for an class
$bsq=new bsq();
//use class function to connect the database
$bsq->connect_db();

//=================================================================================
$reg_id=$_GET["reg_id"];

$where="reg_id='".$_GET["reg_id"]."'";
$web_dataRS=$bsq->webdreamselect('tablename',$where,'','','','');
  $member_data=mysql_fetch_array($web_dataRS);
?>

 //This Table Is Shown When I click On View Details Link On Member's List Page...
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td> Name </td><td><?=$member_data['name'];?></td>
   <td> Address </td><td><?=$member_data['address'];?></td>
   ..
   ..
   ..
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Code In **member_pdf.php** :

```
<?php

    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");


     ob_start();
    //be sure this file exists, and works outside of web context etc.)
    require("http://example.com/admin/memberinfo.php");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("file.pdf");
?>
```

Now problem is , PDF is created But table TDs  containing $member_data['name'] , $member_data['address'] etc are empty.....

See Image =

[image]

Comment: Hard to say, but if short tags are not enabled on the server, you would need to change all `<?` to `<?php` and `<?=` to `<?php echo`. Try that and see if it makes it kick in.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried it just Now...But With No Luck...

Comment: is your memberinfo.php working per se? Do you see the values echoed when you open it? BTW mysql library is deprecated. Use mysqli or better PDO. Short tag <? should not be used (not sure if they have already been removed in the last PHP versions) use <?php. Last but not least you should use echo to printout the variable instead of =

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried your last suggestion... it is saying "Undefined index: reg_id" in memberinfo.php.... basically , I am opening Member's info from member list page By clicking View Details Link. After clicking it is showing information of That specific Reg_Id row...Now memberinfo.php is showing properly....but PDF...till No luck

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am edting updating my memberinfo.php code given in question....

Comment: Should this be the case `reg_id` and `Reg_Id` are not considered the same thing. As you wrote `Reg_Id` in your comment above. Letter-case is important.

Comment: @Fred-ii- memberinfo.php code is edited and updated in question...please see and do needful

Comment: Are you passing the `reg_id` variable to member_pdf.php, e.g. member_pdf.php?reg_id=1?